# Is there a verb that describes speaking with a full mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a verb that describes speaking with a full mouth, like a child asking something at the dinner table before swallowing, because they are so anxious/curious for the answer.  Anything come to mind? I didn't find ANY.

Comment: I think "gross" is the usual word used to describe this.

Comment: "Yeah, it's flmmpf flmmpf flfff, flath, mmmph, blahgggghspf," etc. Don

Comment: Not to be confused with "foul mouth" or to be "foul-mouthed" (i.e., to speak in a profane/blasphemous manner)

Comment: If there were a word for this, generations of kids would not have been told by their parents "Don't talk with your mouth full."

Answer (score 2):

*To talk with one's mouth full*. Example: A parent says to a child at the dinner table, "Don't talk with your mouth full."

Comment: Right, but the question is asking is for a single word that encompasses that entire phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking with your mouth full, as a phrase, means speaking with your mouth *full of food*, but I take it that is not your meaning.

To say something suddenly and without thinking is *to blurt*.

To speak excitedly and at excessive length is *to gabble*.

To speak without making sense (due to anxiety, ignorance, or some other reasons) is *to babble*.

Comment: Yes -- sorry for the confusion -- I did mean - speaking with a mouth full of food - a child eating candy - asking impatiently - to blurt could work - kind of - but it has this rude intonation to it -- which is not the focus here - more the fact that it s hard to understand the question because it is being asked with a mouth full of food

Comment: or is blurting not rude ?? could try it :-))

Comment: No, I would say blurting is usually rude.

Comment: yes, it s not the RUDE aspect I am looking for - but the impatient one ! to ask impatiently -- thats the verb I am looking for

Comment: Just call the man in mind, "Barbarian!"

Comment: Blurting is not necessarily rude, but since you are speaking without thinking, you often say things you wish you had not, either because they are impolite or because they are private.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a specific word for "talking with food in your mouth", but you can certainly describe how it sounds when you talk with food in your mouth:

> "Mom, why do cats chase mice?"  Jimmy *slurred* around a mouthful of peas.
>   "Mom, why do I have to go to school?" Jimmy *garbled*, his mouth full of cereal.

Or you can describe the results of the talking-with-stuff:

> "Mom, will I ever have a sister?"  Jimmy asked, dribbling half-chewed lima beans onto his lap.
>   "Mom, where do babies come from?"  Jimmy demanded as he chewed, flecks of pie spraying out onto the table.

Comment: I think *garble* means "to render unintelligible" and refers to the agent, not the speaker: "The cereal garbled Jimmy's words."  *To slur one's words* carries the unmistakeable implication of mental deficit, often chemically induced.

Comment: ah this is great !! I just saw it - sorry for the late response. Thats what I ended up doing --  your second advice -- i described the food - aka candy -- being eaten. all these words, like garble, slur, gable, mumble, mutter --- all that is somehow not childish enough -- it s a child asking how a game is played - full of excitement and curiosity -- she cant wait to swallow the candy, she must ask right away....

Comment: yes, garble is a voice distorted by something --- the connection kept garbling hos voice -- and to slur is too drunk sounding -- the word cannot be derogatory -- which somehow most of these words are

Answer (score 1):

The closest verb I can come up with is **[sputter](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sputter)**

> verb, intransitive
>   **To spit out or spray particles of saliva or food from the mouth in noisy bursts.**
>
> <sub><sup>The American Heritage Dictionary</sup></sub>

From [Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=lfDZCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT156&dq=%22the%20boy%20sputtered%22%20table&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7ksqdkO7JAhUq8HIKHfLNAhsQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=%22the%20boy%20sputtered%22%20table&f=false) an example

> “What? You *made* me?” The boy sputtered and almost choked on his corn. He wiped his mouth on his sleeve.