# Is there a word for talking without moving your mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests, conversation

I don't mean Ventriloquism exactly, I mean talking around what you may already have in your mouth... For instance say you put something gross in your mouth and ask if its okay to spit it out. 
Example: "Hey this broccoli is so gross. Do I have to eat it?" *said with broccoli in mouth but not ingested"

Sorry this is to crude, I just don't know how to exactly describe it...

Comment: When I was a kid that was called getting sent to your room without supper.

Comment: You're moving your mouth, if not your lips. Etiquette guides call it *[talking/speaking with your mouth full](http://www.mannersmentor.com/social-situations/quick-tip-how-to-talk-with-food-in-your-mouth)*.

Comment: Ewe, that's just disgusting.

Comment: I found something very similar - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225955/is-there-a-verb-that-describes-speaking-with-a-full-mouth

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking without opening your jaw, you are said to be *talking through your teeth*.

If you're talking with food in your mouth, you are said to be *talking with your mouth full*.

If you're actually complaining about having to eat your vegetables with your mouth full, then Buster, you are *skating on thin ice*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ***[mumble](https://www.google.it/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefreedictionary.com%2Fmumble&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefreedictionary.com%2Fmumble&aqs=chrome..69i58j69i57j5&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&hl=it)*** to suggest the idea you are referring to:

> - To speak words indistinctly, as by lowering the voice or partially closing the mouth.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a word to describe that. You can say that his speech was muffled but still understandable, because he couldn't move his lips.

Comment: Muffled, obstructed sound. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I might go about writing it a bit different, and focusing on what the object in the mouth is doing to the normal sound of the speech; "The broccoli in his mouth constricted the words coming out, so that they sounded almost unintelligible."

Comment: Note that the poster is asking for "a word for talking without moving your mouth," not "a way to describe the effect of talking with broccoli in your mouth."